# Add some files and commit in Git

Tags: git, github

I have some files

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

And I want to commit files 1-5 only, so I have added files 1-5

> Changes to be committed:
>
> (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)
>
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

and leave files 6-10 in changes "not staged for commit" list.

But then, when I want to commit using

> git commit -a

I also see those files 6-10

> Changes to be committed:
>
> (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

I think when I have manually added files 1-5, files 6-10 won't be also added in "changes to be committed" list right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git commit -a
```

Adds in files as well as committing. It is equivalent to:

```
git add -u .
git commit
```

From the man page:

> OPTIONS
>          -a, --all
>              Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told git about
>   are not
>              affected.

You just want:

```
git commit
```

To commit only the files you have staged.